# ReactJS- BrowserAuthError: no_account_error: No account object provided to acquireTokenSilent and no active account has been set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, powerbi

I am trying to embed powerbi report to my reactjs web application but I am having trouble to get the embed access token. I am not using any kind of login function to my react web app, it is simple and it shows some details as header and trying show the powerbi report.

I always get error : `BrowserAuthError: no_account_error: No account object provided to acquireTokenSilent and no active account has been set.Please call setActiveAccount or provide an account on the request.`

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { PublicClientApplication} from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { PowerBIEmbed } from 'powerbi-client-react';

const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXXXXXX',
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
    storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
  },
};

const pca = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

function EmbedReport() {
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    pca.handleRedirectPromise().then((response) => {
      if (response !== null && response.account !== null) {
        // set active account
        pca.setActiveAccount(response.account);
        // acquire token
        pca.acquireTokenSilent({ scopes: ['https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default'] })
          .then((response) => {
            setAccessToken(response.accessToken);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {accessToken ? (
        <PowerBIEmbed
          embedConfig={{
            type: 'report',
            id: 'XXXXXXXX',
            embedUrl: 'https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=XXXXXXXXX',
            accessToken: accessToken,
            tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
            settings: {
              panes: {
                filters: {
                  expanded: false,
                  visible: false,
                },
              },
              background: models.BackgroundType.Transparent,
            },
          }}
        />
      ) : (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default EmbedReport;
```

Also i found that `pca.handleRedirectPromise().then((response) => {` gives response`null` always.

more info:
I have created app registration through azure portal. and to that new registration i have selected both `Access token and Id tokes`
I have also created secrets with the app registration, Also i have granted the Api permission for PowerBi service `Read.Readwrite.all`

I am not able to find what i am missing and what do i need to do inorder to get the accesstoken.
Could you hlep me to get the accesstoken so that i can display powerBi report in my react web app.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, user needs to **login atleast once** to retrieve token using `acquireTokenSilent` method. You are facing that error as login function is not implemented in react web app.

If your use case is to get access token **without** user interaction, you can make use of username password flow.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered Azure AD application and granted **API permissions** as below:

[image]

I used below code and got **access token** successfully in response like this:

```js
const getToken = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      body: new URLSearchParams({
        grant_type: 'password',
        client_id: 'c8deab7e-c74d-493e-b662-xxxxxxxx',
        client_secret: 'secret',
        scope: 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default',
        username: 'user1@xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com',
        password: 'password'
      })
    });
  
    const data = await response.json();
    const accessToken = data.access_token;
    return accessToken;  
  };
  
  async function main() {
    const accessToken = await getToken();
    console.log("Access token:",accessToken);
  }
  
  main();
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I decoded the above token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/) and got **`aud`** and **`scp`** claims like below:

[image]

When I used this token to retrieve reports via Postman, I got **response** successfully like this:

```
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: you are using username&password, is there any other way that i don't need to use username and password ?

Comment: Then you can use interactive flows like authorization code flow where you need to implement login function in your webapp.

Comment: Hey @Sridevi, I have a similar issue with getting my accounts. I am using instance.getAllAccounts() but I am only getting an empty array. I've already logged in to microsfot (portal.azure.com, app.powerbi.com) but still my getAllAccounts() fails. You are writing that "Note that, user needs to login atleast once to retrieve token using acquireTokenSilent method." - so they have to login at our page first? Isn't it possible via SSO that we don't need a login at our react app at all? Thank you :)